# Starship prompt: conditional directory color based on path prefix

Tags: bash, starship

Using the [starship prompt](https://starship.rs/), how would I conditionally set the `[directory]` color based on path prefix?

I was able to achieve it in classic bash prompt, and would like to replicate it with starship.

It would work a bit like the `read_only` option of `[directory]` works (adding a lock symbol next to the `[directory]`).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with [custom commands](https://starship.rs/config/#custom-commands). It is not an ideal solution, but it works.

```
[custom.directory1]
format = "[directory1](bg:#33658A)[](fg:#33658A)"
shell = 'bash'
when = '[ "$PWD" == "/path/to/directory1" ]'


[custom.directory2]
format = "[directory2](bg:#4c873f)[](fg:#4c873f)"
shell = 'bash'
when = '[ "$PWD" == "/path/to/directory2" ]'
```